# Why does SQLAlchemy return a new rownum but not insert my new row into MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I am debugging a strange phenomenon rising from this bit of Python code:

```py
def insert_book(name):
   with engine.connect() as connection:
        insert_statement = sqlalchemy.text(
            """
            INSERT INTO books (title_id) 
            SELECT 
                title_id
            FROM titles
            WHERE name = :name;
            """
        ).bindparams(name=name)

        result = connection.execute(insert_statement)
       
        return result.lastrowid
```

The MySQL database tables that I'm working with are structured like so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `titles` (
  `title_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(36),
  PRIMARY KEY (`title_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
);

CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `book_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`),
  KEY `client_id` (`title_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `titles_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`title_id`) REFERENCES `titles` (`title_id`)
);
```

Both tables have several rows already inserted to them.

When I run the Python code (with a `name` taken from the `titles` table) inside a Flask app and point SQLAlchemy to my MySQL DB, two things happen:

1. `result.lastrowid` contains a new auto-incremented int value.
2. A new row is **not** inserted into the table.

As I repeat this, the returned int value is incremented properly but no rows are created.

**My question is:** Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Here are the main packages used:

- Python 3.9.13
- Flask==2.2.2
- PyMySQL==1.1.0
- SQLAlchemy==2.0.19

**PLEASE:** Kindly refrain from pointing in the direction of other, admittedly better, SQLAlchemy APIs. I would like to understand why this specific bit of code is misbehaving. Thank you.

**UPDATE**: I've examined the logs for my cloud instance of MySQL and I'm seeing errors such as these which correspond to failed inserts:

> Aborted connection ... to db: '...' user: '...' host: '...' (Got an error reading communication packets)."

Comment: Replace `with engine.connect()` with `with engine.begin()` and see if the code behaves differently.

Comment: @GordThompson thank you. Your suggestion solved the issue. It seems `engine.connect()` starts a transaction that the code should have committed explicitly but does not.  `engine.build()` starts a transaction and closes automatically it on `__exit__()`. Would you like to promote your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql("INSERT INTO my_table …")
print("Context manager exited.")
```

will automatically roll back the changes because `conn.commit()` was not called. In the [SQLAlchemy tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html#committing-changes) this is known as the "commit as you go" style of working.

By contrast,

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql("INSERT INTO my_table …")
print("Context manager exited.")
```

will automatically commit the changes when the context manager exits (unless an error has occurred). This is called the "begin once" style.